# Stuck in database design, Unable to query result

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle, plsql

I designed my database, in which I have 4 quarters in a year, and I have 3 values for year i.e

```
2015 (Quarter 1) | 2014 (Quarter 1) | 2013 (Quarter 1)
```

It is like, if I chose 2014 (Quarter 1) it would be like

```
2014 (Quarter 1) | 2013 (Quarter 1) | 2012 (Quarter 1).
```

Same goes for other quarters. My database table is like:

```
First_Year | Second_Year | Third_Year | For_Year | Quarter_Year | CODE 
12         | 15          | 16         | 2015     |      1       | Interest_Earned
6          | 5           |  6         | 2015     |      1       | Interest_Expense
```

Now lets say, my `First_Year = For_Year` (2015 in this case), my `Second_Year = For_Year - 1` (become 2014 in this case) and my `Third_Year = For_Year - 2` (2013 according to mentioned table).

I want to query these results and populate in ASP.NET TextBoxes with help of PL SQL. Lets say user chose Quarter 1 and Year 2015 on front end via DropDown list, I have to select data for Quarter 1 and 2015, which is easy, and all other fields too.

But if I am going to enter data for year 2016, I would have data available for 2015 and 2014 in advance (see in table I have data available). When I will be entering data for year 2016 I should not re-enter data for year 2015 and 2014. That's where I would stuck, because I can't copy my data again and again. I would have no issue to copy data again and again for sake of completing it, still I am clueless. How would I only choose related data to populate my TextBoxes and report.

Lets say, I choose 2016 data, so in this case, I will have to populate my TextBoxes, related to data of 2015 and 2014, but because I'll have no data available for year 2016, TextBoxes of that part will be empty. Kindly help me out in it.

Should I change my design? I completed around 80% of my work and now I am facing hard deadline.

In easy words, I am making Capital Adequacy Report on Capital Risk Operations.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question, can you rewrite it into separate paragraphs, showing what results you want to get for each query.

Comment: what are the business requirements, and how would the product look like?  I'm not sure I understand the question, but I think the problem could be the way you structured the tables.

Comment: I agree with @AmmarHamidou - you appear to have built your tables based on the layout of the UI (the Report) rather than on sound principles of data modelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would 100% absolutely recommend changing your database design as it is not sustainable as it is currently structured. You are fortunate you are running into problems so quickly as sometimes poor design can exist for years before running into a deal-breaker (at which time redesign can be financially off the table).

Read up on [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), [3rd Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) (your goal for data normalization) and check out some tutorials about how to take a dataset and make them 3NF.

As a hint, all of your column data should be listed within the same row, and data should be separated so as to exclude duplication like:

Time Table:

```
ID   | Year | Quarter
1401 | 2014 |  1     
1502 | 2015 |  2
1501 | 2015 |  1
```

Value Table:

```
TimeID | ExpenseCode      | Value
1401   | Interest_Earned  |  10
1502   | Interest_Expense |  25
```

The purpose of this is so that eventually you can perform complex queries using  ANSI [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) like:

```
SELECT Sum(Value) 
FROM ValueTable
WHERE TimeID Between [BoundVariable] and [BoundVariable];
```

This will allow you to perform complex queries within the database engine itself as opposed to building intense logic within your `c#` front end. Just make sure to read up on [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [3-Tier architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) to ensure that you aren't introducing any issues with your redesign.